# I am trying to write a program in C that prompts user for a name and then outputs its initials

Tags: c, loops

The following is what I wrote first. It worked perfectly well for one space between strings.

```
int main(void)
{
    string name = GetString();
    printf("%c",toupper(name[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
    {
        if (name[i] == ' ')
        {
            i++;
            printf("%c", toupper(name[i]));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

However, since it detects only one space, it won't work for user input with multiple spaces between two strings. So, I went ahead and created a do while loop as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    string name = GetString();
    printf("%c",toupper(name[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
    {
        do
        {
            if (name[i] == ' ')
            {
               i++;
               printf("%c", toupper(name[i]));
            }
        }
        while (name[i+1] != ' ');
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

While I was expecting the loop to do it for me, now, my terminal is only prompting for almost an infinite number of user input of names and printing absolutely nothing. I cannot seem to be able to detect the error. This is only my first week programming, help please!

Comment: What is string in declaration string name = GetString();?

Comment: Please show the GetString function, and if `string` is a typedef (or macro) for `char*`, get rid of that ASAP.

Comment: std::string is C++, not C.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm: code wouldn't compile if that was a C++ `std::string` (you can't call `strlen` on a `std::string`).

Comment: Normally a C program starts with one or more `#include` directives. If you have any, please show them.

Comment: @Mat, you are right. I inattentive considered the code.

Comment: I am taking a cs50 class, and it has its own directory. so my library looks like this:

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the next space by using checking if next is a space simply:

```
if (name[i] == ' ' && name[i+1] != ' ')
```

in your first program.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
    {
        if (name[i] == ' ' && name[i+1] != ' ')
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(name[i+1]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main logic of the program can look the following way. I used as an example a character array because I do not know how name `string` is defined

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
//  string name = GetString();
    char name[] = "yashmin sainju";

    char *p = name;

    while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
    if ( *p )  printf( "%c.", toupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) );

    while ( *p && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
    while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
    if ( *p )  printf( " %c.\n", toupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
Y. S.
```

If your compiler does not support function `isblank` you can substitute it for expression

```
( *p == ' ' || *p == '\t' )
```